# shall we rerun `createrepo` after copying new files in repository

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I have a repository installed. I want to update that repository with new rpm files. Can I rerun `createrepo` command on this repository in order to make my new files available to the servers using that repository?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need `--update` option with `createrepo`

createrepo --update: Sometimes you have a lot of packages in your repsitory and regenerating the meta data for each package when only a few packages have been added or changed is just too time consuming. This is where --update comes in handy. You run createrepo just like you did before but you pass the --update flag to it. Like this:

```
  createrepo --update </path/to/repo>
```

Now, createrepo will only update the items which have been changed, been added or been removed since the last time the meta data was generated.

Also mentioned in `man createrepo`

([Reference](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoCreate#MoreAdvancedoptions))

Comment: Okay, I'm being a bit pedantic here, but you don't *need* to use `--update`. Without it, `createrepo` will create the metadata just fine. But `--update` will massively speed it up, especially in large repositories.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. After any modification in repo directory, you should run `createrepo` on it.
Of course, clients should run `yum clean all` before changes are seen.